# How to show dialog overlapping protection on android?

Tags: android, dialog

my dialog inheritance dialogFragment.

when I button click, show dialog.

but I button Click multiple times. show multiple dialog.(overlap dialog)

I want show only one dialog.

I try this.

```
if (dialog.getDialog().isShowing()){
    //not showing dialog 
} else {
    dialog.show();
}
```

but not work.

how to show dialog overlapping protection on android?

Answer (score 0):

Dismiss the dialog when its open already

```
if (dialog.isShowing()){
 dialog.dismiss();
} else {
dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: my dialog inheritance dialogFragment . so not use `dialog.isShowing()`

Comment: then use dialog.getDialog().isShowing()

Answer (score 0):

If u want to prevent multiple click use some thing like this

```
 button.setClickable(false);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                button.setClickable(true);
            }
        }, 2000);
```

Delay = 2 sec.

Answer (score 0):

**try this define one variable**

```
private int count = 0;
                if (count == 0) {
                    dialog.show();
                    count++;
                }
```

**when you dissmis the dialog at that time**

```
btnCustomDiscard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        customDialog.dismiss();
                        count = 0;

                    }
                });
```

i hope it will helpful for you.